# how to write a function that prints out mean value of prime numbers in c

Tags: c, primes

I'm trying to solve a problem, where I am supposed to write a function that prints out the mean value of all prime numbers between 2 and N but I don't know how to start. I have already written a function that prints out all the prime numbers.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the mean? You say you already have the hard part done.

Comment: When talking about code, please *show the code*. We can only guess what you've done so far and how to take it to the finish line.

Comment: Yes I know how to calculate the mean value, you add all the prime numbers and divide that sum by the number of primes. But I don't really know how to implement that into code

Comment: So instead of printing number add it to some accumulator variable and increment the number of total primes found. Then divide one by other.

Comment: You don't know how to add them up, or your don't know how to count them, or you don't know how to divide the sum by the count, or you don't know how to print it? If you store the sum and the count as integers, you probably want to store the mean as a floating point value and do a floating point division, something like `double mean = (double)sum / count;`.

Comment: @mkmk for future posts its always a good idea to provide any current attempts at solving the problem so that we (the community) can more easily frame the response. ie post your current code that prints out the prime numbers

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. sum the prime numbers as you find them instead of printing
2. also count the number of primes you found
3. then divide the sum by number of primes

for example, assuming you have written the function for prime :

```
 count=0;
 for(i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            sum+=i;
            count++;
        }
    }
 mean = sum/count; // watch for integer division
```